# pyOpenSSL's PKCS7 object provide very little information, how can I get the sha1 digest of the public key in the signature

Tags: android, python, cryptography, pkcs#7, pyopenssl

I would like to parse android apk's CERT.RSA in Python.
I know it can be parsed with pyOpenSSL

```
import OpenSSL
```

<s>cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, 
    open('CERT.RSA', 'rb').read())</s>

```
cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs7_data(type, buffer)
```

cert is of type 'OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7'.

BUT right now PKCS7 object is not complete, I cannot get attributes I need, is there any alternative way to parse that file?

Comment: What attributes are you looking for?

Comment: I need the sha1 digest of the public key in the signature

Comment: @stovfl 
Compared with PKCS12, PKCS7 have few attributes and methods.
I don't know if there's a way to convert it to another format so it can be parsed.

[pyopenssle doc](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/crypto.html#pkcs7-objects)

    PKCS7 objects
    PKCS7 objects have the following methods:

    PKCS7.type_is_signed()
    FIXME

    PKCS7.type_is_enveloped()
    FIXME

    PKCS7.type_is_signedAndEnveloped()
    FIXME

    PKCS7.type_is_data()
    FIXME

    PKCS7.get_type_name()
    Get the type name of the PKCS7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Comments**:  I don't know if there's a way to convert it to another format so it can be parsed

You can convert `PKCS#7` to `PEM` using `openssl`, `PEM` is readable using `PyOpenSSL`

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in sample.p7b -out sample.cer
```

---

> **Question**: ... how can I get the sha1 digest of the public key in the signature

It's not implemented, the Pull Request stalles since 2015.
Useing the code from the Pull Request you can doit.

> **From**: GitHub pyca/pyopenssl:
>    [implement getters for pkcs#7 certificates, crl's, and data #367](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/367)
>
> ```
>     def get_certificates(self):
>         from OpenSSL.crypto import _lib, _ffi, X509
>         """
>         https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/pull/367/files#r67300900
>
>         Returns all certificates for the PKCS7 structure, if present. Only
>         objects of type ``signedData`` or ``signedAndEnvelopedData`` can embed
>         certificates.
>
>         :return: The certificates in the PKCS7, or :const:`None` if
>             there are none.
>         :rtype: :class:`tuple` of :class:`X509` or :const:`None`
>         """
>         certs = _ffi.NULL
>         if self.type_is_signed():
>             certs = self._pkcs7.d.sign.cert
>         elif self.type_is_signedAndEnveloped():
>             certs = self._pkcs7.d.signed_and_enveloped.cert
>
>         pycerts = []
>         for i in range(_lib.sk_X509_num(certs)):
>             pycert = X509.__new__(X509)
>             # pycert._x509 = _lib.sk_X509_value(certs, i)
>             # According to comment from @ Jari Turkia
>             # to prevent segfaults use '_lib.X509_dup('
>             pycert._x509 = _lib.X509_dup(_lib.sk_X509_value(certs, i))
>             pycerts.append(pycert)
>
>         if not pycerts:
>             return None
>         return tuple(pycerts)
> ```

**Usage:**

```
pkcs7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, open('signature.der', 'rb').read())
certs = get_certificates(pkcs7)
print(certs)
for cert in certs:
    print('digest:{}'.format(cert.digest('sha256')))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> (<OpenSSL.crypto.X509 object at 0xf671b62c>, <OpenSSL.crypto.X509 object at 0xf671b86c>)
> digest:b'48:19:A4:2A:56:94:22:14:73:EC:2B:01:45:9E:0B:87:92:44:26:5E:57:AF:59:F5:4C:89:F3:79:83:14:11:A3'
> digest:b'25:BC:AC:86:8F:51:8B:EE:47:CC:8B:A7:78:91:7E:86:09:56:19:4B:B9:C4:10:1B:DF:13:CA:A6:54:E1:F7:4C'
> ```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - OpenSSL:17.1.0 - cryptography:1.9 - cffi:1.10.0***

---

Use

```
OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs7_data(type, buffer)
```

> Load pkcs7 data from the string buffer encoded with the type type.
>   The type type must either FILETYPE_PEM or FILETYPE_ASN1).

Comment: My bad. 

Yes, the command should be this one.

The return value is of type `OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7`

How can I get the sha1 digest of the public key then?

Comment: @stovfl can this be extended to show information like CN, OU, O, ST etc? Basically anything the X509Name class can handle?

Comment: @securisec: You get a X509 object. From this object you can get the "issuers"X509Name object. See: https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509-objects

Comment: Cannot do `pycert._x509 = _lib.sk_X509_value(certs, i)` as the data will be lost. Changed into `pycert._x509 = _lib.X509_dup(_lib.sk_X509_value(certs, i))`. This copies the bytes first and assigns to a new X509 cert. No more segfaults.