# Is there any python package for parsing pkcs7?

Tags: android, python, pkcs#7, androguard

I'm extracting features from Android .APK files with [androguard](https://github.com/androguard/androguard) and right now I need to extract the serial number(*) from its signature file (usually CERT.RSA). I've found [asn1crypto](https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto), but I don't quite understand, how to use it with pkcs7. So is there any python package suitable for this purpose?

(*):
[image: Serial number]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Comment**:  I have pkcs7 as a memory object, not a file

`PyOpenSSL` does not read from *file*!

> OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs7_data(type, buffer)
>
> Load pkcs7 data from the string buffer encoded with the type type.
>      The type type must either FILETYPE_PEM or FILETYPE_ASN1).

`from`[`SO Answer 45111623`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104923/pyopenssls-pkcs7-object-provide-very-little-information-how-can-i-get-the-sha1#answer-45111623)`import get_certificates`

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
pkcs7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, 
                               open('certs/signature.der', 'rb').read())
certs = get_certificates(pkcs7)
for cert in certs:
    print('Subject:{}, Serial Nnumber:{}'.
        format(cert.get_subject(), cert.get_serial_number()))

>>>Subject:<X509Name object '/CN=key1'>, Serial Nnumber:13315126025841024674
>>>Subject:<X509Name object '/CN=key2'>, Serial Nnumber:14142490995367396705
```

---

> **Question**: python package for parsing pkcs7?

You can convert PKCS#7 to PEM using openssl, PEM is readable using [PyOpenSSL](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509-objects)

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in sample.p7b -out sample.cer
```

---

Read that relevant SO Answer: [pyOpenSSL's PKCS7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111623/7414759)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already know that, but I have pkcs7 as a memory object, not a file. It's not that I couldn't save it as a file, I just wanted to do it this way. That's why I wanted to find a python package so bad. Anyway, since a signature has always the same structure I simply parse ASN1 directly with [asn1 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asn1/2.1.0) and extract a serial number.

Comment: `get_certificates()` defined here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104923/pyopenssls-pkcs7-object-provide-very-little-information-how-can-i-get-the-sha1#answer-45111623

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'OpenSSL' has no attribute 'get_certificates'`, What is `get_certificates`?

Comment: @e-info128 ***What is `get_certificates`"?"***: Follow the link in **fromSO Answer 45111623 `import get_certificates`**

Comment: Some of the features of this packages are deprecated.. like support of x509.
So its better to use [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) 

Please take a look at [this](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html?highlight=cryptography#OpenSSL.crypto.X509.from_cryptography)